# octave slow, optimisation advice needed

Tags: octave

The loop takes a long time to execute. Is there a faster way of processing the loaded file?

```
a = fileread ("C:/Backup/Thermo Backups/2018-05-17.txt"); 
d = strsplit (a, "\n");
for i = 1 : length(d) 
  e (i , :) = strsplit ( d{i} );
endfor 
f = cellfun(@str2num, e)
```

Data sample:

```
2   36.5333 43  43  43  43  68  0   0
2.5 36.5333 43  43  43  43  68  0   0
3   36.6667 43  43  43  43  68  0   0
3.5 36.6667 43  43  43  43  68  0   0
4   36.6667 43  43  43  43  68  0   0
```

Comment: Pre-allocate `e`: before the loop, write `e = cell(length(d),N)` (replace `N` with whatever the size of the result is).

Comment: Please provide a sample of `a`  or `2018-05-17.txt` and expected result `f`

Comment: You're looping through, then essentially looping through again with `cellfun`. I cannot test because you've not given a [mcve], but removing the loop and using `f = cellfun( @(di) str2num(strsplit(di)), d )` should work, no?

Comment: thanks @Cris. 
I wasn't able to execute your command, Wolfie